# Calculate total from values stored in Firebase Firestore Database-Android

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get total value of a collection fields from cloud Firestore database. Not success. Please help me.

```
DocumentReference productsRef = firebaseFirestore
        .collection("report").document(userID)
        .collection("year").document(userID2)
        .collection("month").document(userID3)
        .collection("report").document();

productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            double total = 0;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                double itemCost = document.getDouble("total");
                total += itemCost;
            }
           // Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(total));
            dtotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: "Not success" is really hard to help with. When you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run in the debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line: what is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Glad to know that now I have solved it by myself...

```
    DocumentReference productsRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("report").document(userID)
            .collection("year").document(userID2)
            .collection("month").document(userID3);

    Query query = productsRef.collection("report");

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    String itemCost = document.getString("total");
                    int total = Integer.parseInt(itemCost);
                    sum = sum + total;
                    dtotal.setText(String.valueOf(sum));


                }


            }
        }
    });
```